# Meeting Attendees Don't Appear in Calendar

Tags: 2010, meeting-workspace

When I view the "All Events" list containing a number of meetings using workspaces, and choose to see the "Attendees" column, it is always empty.

I understand that the Attendees in the Meeting Workspace is a separate list, but surely it should update the Calendar list's "Attendees" column by default, otherwise what is the point of having the column?

Is there a way to enable this or will I have to write a workflow?

Comment: We are facing same issue. Even if we add them manually they don't appear for reccurent meeting.